# How to handle translation correct way?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Some background: On the site I'm maintaining, I installed [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module and also enabled `Node Translation`. I added a few languages, then set a node's language to French and site default language to English.

When the site's current language is set to French, the node shows up as `en/node/28`, however shows up as `fr/sous-specialites` when the current language is French. How do I work this around?

UPDATE: Detection and Selection page has URL, Session, User and Browser enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the url alias to be `/sous-specialites` for the english node. If so, I think you can use [Global redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module.

> From the documentation,
>
> What?
>
> GlobalRedirect is a simple module which…
>
> - Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if it is not being used.
> - Checks the current URL for a trailing slash, removes it if present and repeats check 1 with the new request.
> - Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.
> - Checks if the Clean URLs feature is enabled and then checks the current URL is being accessed using the clean method rather than the
>     'unclean' method.
> - Checks access to the URL. If the user does not have access to the path, then no redirects are done. This helps avoid exposing private
>     aliased node's.
> - Make sure the case of the URL being accessed is the same as the one set by the author/administrator. For example, if you set the alias
>     "articles/cake-making" to node/123, then the user can access the alias
>     with any combination of case.
> - Most of the above options are configurable in the settings page. In Drupal 5 you can access this after enabling the globalredirect_admin
>     module. In Drupal 6, the settings page is bundled into the module.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1:

The order specified at `Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection` could be what explains the current behaviour in your site.

You'd have to experiment a bit with what the exact order in your case should be. But in my experience, I often get these kind of issues to work by using an order like "`URL, Default, User`", and not something like "`Default, URL, User`". So try to experiment a bit with the various combinations in this order to check if it helps.

## Option 2:

Another reason why such issue / problem may occur, is because [Language detection by domain only works on port 80](https://www.drupal.org/node/1572394) and/or [URL generation only works on port 80](https://www.drupal.org/node/1645156). Those issues have 'some patches' attached to it, and status = *Needs review*.

So if you're not using port 80, then you may want to try/consider experimenting with any of the patches in these issues.